# Azure Function Application warm up state

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions, warm-up, cold-start

I am currently using multiple azure function app instances,
with the "apiVersion": "2015-08-01" .
Currently I dont use any warmup triggers and only few functions stay always in "warmup" state, even
when restart the application is goes to warmup state very soon ,anyone with the same experience
and found a solution ?

ARM Template

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "name": "[variables('xx')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "kind": "functionapp",
  "identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('xx'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('xx'))]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "appSettings": [
      
      ]
    }
  }
```

Starter

```
[FunctionName("xxStarter")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("xxQueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        xx xxMessage,[DurableClient]IDurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log)
    {
       
        string instanceId  = await starter.StartNewAsync("xxOchestration", xxMessage);
     

        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The "WarmUp" in your screenshot isn't a state, this Function App currently holds one Function with the **name** WarmUp.
It is weird that there doesn't seem to be a trigger for the Function though. What are you hosting this on? Consumption, App Service Plan or Premium?

Comment: There are many other functions are there ,but as this warmup things shows up ,real functions even dont show up there

Comment: Could you share some code? Looks/sounds like something isn't right.

Comment: i have added the ARM files and starter function @rickvdbosch